Can we view higher homotopy groups as symmetries?
If we want to think of a group as representing symmetry, we want it to act on something. In the case of the fundamental group of a (nice) topological space $X$, even though it's definition doesn't a priori have to do with symmetry, it turns out that $\pi_1(X)$ acts faithfully on the universal cover of $X$ by deck transformations. So even though $\pi_1(X)$ isn't the symmetries of $X$ itself, it is the symmetries of a construction related to $X$.
Are there any natural actions of higher homotopy groups that let us view them as symmetries of something related to $X$?
(Of course, every group acts on its underlying set, but I'm wondering if there's a less tautological action that's actually related to the topology of $X$.)

All of the higher homotopy groups are also fundamental groups, so your construction with the universal cover also applies to them. Namely,
$$\pi_2(X) \cong \pi_1(\Omega X)$$
where $\Omega X$ is the based loop space of $X$ (at the same basepoint at which we're taking homotopy groups, which is being suppressed in this notation), so $\pi_2(X)$ also acts by symmetries, on the universal cover of $\Omega X$. This universal cover, when interpreted directly in terms of $X$, is (up to homotopy) the based loop space of the second stage of the Whitehead tower of $X$. This is a kind of "higher universal cover" of $X$ which trivializes its first two homotopy groups. (However, unlike the universal cover itself, it doesn't have a nice point-set description in general, e.g. it is not guaranteed to be a manifold if $X$ is a manifold or anything like that; it is really a homotopy-theoretic construction.)
Similarly $\pi_n(X) \cong \pi_1(\Omega^{n-1} X)$ and the same applies here.
